# My program seems to be ignoring my compareTo() I wrote

Tags: java, compareto

I was given code and had to fill in the `compareTo` section. For whatever reason, even if I comment out my `compareTo` code, Java will still give me a result when I call it which leads me to believe I must be calling it wrong. I'm at a loss with this one.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class testString implements Comparable<testString> {
    String tempStr;

    public testString(String str) {
        tempStr = str;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return tempStr;
    }

    public int compareTo(testString Str2) {
        String temp = Str2.toString();
        int temp1 = temp.length();

        if (tempStr.length() > temp1) {
            return 1;
        } else if (tempStr.length() < temp1) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }      
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        String [] Array1 = new String[]{"dog","giraffe","python","emu","elephant","cow"};

        System.out.print(Array1[1].compareTo(Array1[0]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The array created in the main method contains `String` objects, not `testString` objects. If you want to compare instances of the `testString` class, then create an array of those objects.

```
testString[] array1 = new testString[]{new testString("dog")...};
```

Also note that class names should be capitalized, and variables begin with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Also, if I want to call this compareTo method from another class within the same package, would I need to do the same thing, where as I create an array like above, just in a different class?

Comment: Depends what you want to do, but this sounds reasonable. Best way to find out is to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Array1` is an array of `String`. ; ) So it calls `compareTo` from `String`.

What you probably want is something like:

```
TestString[] array1 = new TestString[] {
    new TestString("dog"),
    new TestString("giraffe"),
    new TestString("python"),
    new TestString("emu"),
    new TestString("elephant"),
    new TestString("cow")
};

System.out.print(array1[1].compareTo(array1[0]));
```

As a side note:

- Classes in Java start with an uppercase letter by convention (`TestString`).
- Variables in Java start with a lowercase letter by convention (`array1`).
- You should use the `@Override` annotation:

  ```
  @Override
  public String toString() {...}
  @Override
  public int compareTo(...) {...}
  ```

  This will cause a compiler error and warn you if there's a problem and you aren't actually overriding. (Such as happens with a typo or incorrect parameter type.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll make sure I'm following the convention, wasn't aware of that.

Comment: It's really a small thing, it just makes it easier to read for Java programmers who are used to the convention. The syntax highlighting here uses it as a hint too.